# Vue3 Button not functioning - undefined property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuejs3

I'm having issues with a non-functioning button on the screenshot below, hopefully you can help.

[Button functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45yki.jpg)

The button itself doesn't click, yet I can successfully submit the data by pressing Enter. Inspect shows an error 'Cannot read propertises of undefined (reading 'forEach'). The code for these is below, there's only 2 instances - this is the instance on line 255:

```
      getData() {
    const data = {
      questions: [],
      answers: []
    }

    this.questions.forEach(question => {
      if (question.title) {
        let answer = question.answer
        if (Array.isArray(answer)) {
          answer = answer.join(', ')
        }

        data.questions.push(question.title)
        data.answers.push(answer)
      }
    })

    return data
  }
```

and at line 220:

```
onSendData(questionList) {
    // Set `submitted` to true so the form knows not to allow back/forward
    // navigation anymore.

    const QuestionsArray = []

    questionList.forEach(question => {
      QuestionsArray.push(question.answer)
    })

    this.$refs.flowform.submitted = true

    this.submitted = false
```

The code for the button itself:

```
 <template v-slot:completeButton>
     <div class="f-submit" v-if="!submitted">
         <button class="o-btn-action"
                 ref="button"
                 type="submit"
                 href="#"
                 v-on:click="onSendData(questionList)"
                 aria-label="Press to submit">
             <span>{{ language.submitText }}</span>
         </button>
         <a class="f-enter-desc"
            href="#"
            v-on:click="onSendData(questionList)"
            v-html="language.formatString(language.pressEnter)">
         </a>
     </div>

     <p class="text-success" v-if="submitted">Submitted succesfully.</p>
 </template>
</flow-form>
```

Funnily enough, I can only replicate this issue when using this Vue repo with another in the same stack, when I deploy it standalone, it works fine!

Full code:

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <header class="vff-header">
      <div class="f-container">
       <!-- Add custom logo here -->
        <svg class="f-logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 35.606 11.211">
          <path d="M.134.837H3.21V8.01h4.203v2.18H.134V.837z"/>
          <path d="M11.875.59c1.48 0 2.668.448 3.567 1.344s1.35 2.052 1.35 3.47c0 1.48-.445 2.7-1.336 3.632S13.38 10.45 11.9 10.45c-1.678 0-2.954-.54-3.827-1.622-.717-.9-1.08-2.022-1.09-3.397-.01-1.36.39-2.484 1.193-3.374C9.06 1.08 10.292.59 11.875.59zm0 2.283c-.563 0-1.003.222-1.323.662-.338.467-.507 1.124-.507 1.972 0 .865.162 1.524.487 1.978a1.58 1.58 0 0 0 1.369.682c.588 0 1.04-.223 1.355-.668s.474-1.07.474-1.875c0-1.834-.62-2.75-1.855-2.75z"/>
          <path d="M21.565 7.078V5.055h4.217v5.163h-1.986l-.13-.908c-.693.76-1.617 1.142-2.777 1.142-1.383 0-2.488-.437-3.313-1.3s-1.243-2.03-1.252-3.464c-.01-1.462.385-2.65 1.18-3.567.875-1.012 2.11-1.518 3.7-1.518 1.21 0 2.207.303 3 .907s1.264 1.457 1.447 2.556h-2.92c-.207-.787-.73-1.182-1.57-1.182-.553 0-.988.236-1.303.707s-.475 1.153-.475 2.043c0 1.695.652 2.542 1.96 2.542.363 0 .695-.103.998-.306a1.29 1.29 0 0 0 .572-.784h-1.35v.002z"/>
          <path d="M30.556.59c1.48 0 2.668.448 3.568 1.344s1.348 2.052 1.348 3.47c0 1.48-.443 2.7-1.336 3.632S32.06 10.45 30.58 10.45c-1.678 0-2.953-.54-3.826-1.622-.72-.892-1.082-2.022-1.1-3.398-.008-1.357.39-2.48 1.193-3.372C27.74 1.08 28.974.59 30.556.59zm0 2.283c-.563 0-1.002.222-1.322.662-.336.467-.506 1.125-.506 1.972 0 .865.162 1.524.486 1.978s.78.682 1.37.682 1.04-.223 1.355-.668.475-1.07.475-1.875c-.002-1.834-.62-2.75-1.857-2.75z"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </header>

    <flow-form
      ref="flowform"
      v-on:complete="onComplete"
      v-on:submit="onSubmit"
      v-bind:questions="questions"
      v-bind:language="language"
      v-bind:standalone="true"
    >
    <!-- Custom content for the Complete/Submit screen slots in the FlowForm component -->
      <!-- We've overriden the default "complete" slot content -->
     <template v-slot:complete>
        <div class="f-section-wrap">
          <p>
            <span class="fh2">Thank you. </span>
            <span class="f-section-text">
              Great work, the survey is completed, and our mint is done. You can review your answers or press submit.
            </span>
          </p>
          <p class="f-description">Note: No data will be saved and/or sent in this demo.</p>
        </div>  
      </template>

      <!-- We've overriden the default "completeButton" slot content -->
     <template v-slot:completeButton>
         <div class="f-submit" v-if="!submitted">
             <button class="o-btn-action"
                     ref="button"
                     type="submit"
                     href="#"
                     v-on:click="onSendData(questionList)"
                     aria-label="Press to submit">
                 <span>{{ language.submitText }}</span>
             </button>
             <a class="f-enter-desc"
                href="#"
                v-on:click="onSendData(questionList)"
                v-html="language.formatString(language.pressEnter)">
             </a>
         </div>

         <p class="text-success" v-if="submitted">Submitted succesfully.</p>
     </template>
    </flow-form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  /*
    Copyright (c) 2020 - present, DITDOT Ltd. - MIT Licence
    https://www.ditdot.hr/en
  */

  // Import necessary components and classes
  import FlowForm from '../../src/components/FlowForm.vue'
  import QuestionModel, { QuestionType, ChoiceOption, LinkOption } from '../../src/models/QuestionModel'
  import LanguageModel from '../../src/models/LanguageModel'
  // If using the npm package, use the following line instead of the ones above.
  // import FlowForm, { QuestionModel, QuestionType, ChoiceOption, LanguageModel } from '@ditdot-dev/vue-flow-form'

  export default {
    name: 'example',

    components: {
      FlowForm
    },

    data() {
      return {
        submitted: false,
        completed: false,
        language: new LanguageModel(),
        // Create question list with QuestionModel instances
        questions: [
          new QuestionModel({
            id: 'MC1',
            tagline: 'First MC question',
            title: 'Interests, select all relevant:',
            helpTextShow: false,
            type: QuestionType.MultipleChoice,
            multiple: true,
            allowOther: true,
            required: true,
            options: [
              new ChoiceOption({
                label: 'Cars'
              }),
              new ChoiceOption({
                label: 'Sports'
               }),
              new ChoiceOption({
                label: 'Animals'
              })
            ]
          }),
          new QuestionModel({
            id: 'MC2',
            title: 'Colours now:',
            type: QuestionType.MultipleChoice,
            multiple: true,
            helpText: 'Select all that you like. ',
            required: true,
            options: [
              new ChoiceOption({
                label: 'Blue'
              }),
              new ChoiceOption({
                label: 'Red'
              }),
              new ChoiceOption({
                label: 'Green'
              }),
              new ChoiceOption({
                label: 'Yellow'
              })
            ]
          }),
                    new QuestionModel({
                        id: 'choose_path',
                        tagline: 'Where would you like answer on hobbies? ',
                        title: 'Hobby choice:',
                        type: QuestionType.Dropdown,
                        multiple: false,
                        placeholder: 'Select',
                        inline: true,
                        required: true,
                        options: [
                            new ChoiceOption({
                                label: 'No more questions',
                                value: 'path_a'
                            }),
                            new ChoiceOption({
                                label: 'Go to Hobbies',
                                value: 'path_b'
                            })
                        ],
                        jump: {
                            path_b: 'path_b'
                        }
                    }),
                    new QuestionModel({
                        id: 'path_a',
                        title: 'Fine, lets finish! ',
                        content: 'Press enter or use the continue button for the final submit screen.',
                        type: QuestionType.SectionBreak,
                        jump: {
                            _other: '_submit'
                        }
                    }),
                    new QuestionModel({
                        id: 'path_b',
                        tagline: 'Hobbies',
                        title: 'Do you like the below?',
                        helpTextshow: false,
                        type: QuestionType.MultipleChoice,
                        multiple: false,
                        required: true,
                        options: [
                            new ChoiceOption({
                                label: 'Snooker',
                            }),
                            new ChoiceOption({
                                label: 'Fishing'
                            })
                        ],
                        jump: {
                            path_a: 'path_a'
                        }
                    })
                ]
            }
        },

    mounted() {
      document.addEventListener('keyup', this.onKeyListener)
    },

    beforeUnmount() {
      document.removeEventListener('keyup', this.onKeyListener)
    },

    methods: {
      onKeyListener($event) {
        // We've overriden the default "complete" slot so
        // we need to implement the "keyup" listener manually.

        if ($event.key === 'Enter' && this.completed && !this.submitted) {
          this.onSendData(questionList)
        }
      },

      /* eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars */
      onComplete(completed, questionList) {
        // This method is called whenever the "completed" status is changed.
        this.completed = completed
      },

      /* eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars */
      onSubmit(questionList) {
        // This method will only be called if you don't override the
        // completeButton slot.

        this.onSendData(questionList)
      },
      
      onSendData(questionList) {
        // Set `submitted` to true so the form knows not to allow back/forward
        // navigation anymore.

        const QuestionsArray = []

        questionList.forEach(question => {
          QuestionsArray.push(question.answer)
        })

        this.$refs.flowform.submitted = true

        this.submitted = false

        /* eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars */
        const data = this.getData()
        //console.log(email)

          fetch('https://auth-32463-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/test.json', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            Q1: QuestionsArray[0],
            Q2: QuestionsArray[1],
            Q3: QuestionsArray[2],
            Q4: QuestionsArray[3],

          })
        });
        },

      getData() {
        const data = {
          questions: [],
          answers: []
        }

        this.questions.forEach(question => {
          if (question.title) {
            let answer = question.answer
            if (Array.isArray(answer)) {
              answer = answer.join(', ')
            }

            data.questions.push(question.title)
            data.answers.push(answer)
          }
        })

        return data
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style lang="css">
  @import '../../src/assets/css/themes/theme-minimal.css';
  /* If using the npm package, use the following lines instead of the one above */
  /* @import '~@ditdot-dev/vue-flow-form/dist/vue-flow-form.css'; */
  /* @import '~@ditdot-dev/vue-flow-form/dist/vue-flow-form.theme-minimal.css'; */
</style>
```

Comment: Please provide a full example of the code. or reproduce the issue on StackOverflow snippet or any live code editor like codesandbox.

Comment: Sorry @Mina - edited with full code included

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem on your **onKeyListener** when you call the **this.onSendData** function you're only passing **questionList** you need to use **this.questionList**. And on the **onSubmit** function check if you're receiving the list correctly too.

Comment: Hi Alexandre, thanks very much for answering. I changed this.onSendData(questionList) to this.onSendData(this.questionList) without success. 

When I use 'Enter' the question list is being passed correctly to the Firebase database.

Comment: I've found some point, the variable **questionList** is used only as parameter in some methods, you don't instantiate it, right? So if this is right on your button call you need to use the **questions** variable, and also in the **onKeyListener**